# Cannot connect to the database with Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm building a website with play! framework, I've finished coding and testing with in memory database, and everything was fine, so I decided to push the code to my server. But I encountered with a strange error, it says, "A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Unknown database 'fpn_server'".

I did change the application.conf file in conf folder, I set the application.mode to prod(quite sure this has no connection with database), set the db property to "mysql:root:mypass@fpn_server", and jpa.ddl to "create" to make sure the database got created.

Well, to be honest, I developed a demo website with the same database name, and it was successfully deployed on my server. But this time, the schema changed, I did NOT use the evolution scripts as the documentation said, I simply dropped the database from mysql server. Not quite sure if this is the mistake.

I've been googling around for a while, an no good.

BTW, I'm usin play 1.2.4 not play 2.

Can anyone help me? Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The connection should be like this: db=mysql://user:pwd@host/database

Comment: this is not the play style connection string, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the shortcut MYSQL5 configuration, which appears fine. However, maybe you should try using the verbose settings.

```
%production.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/fpn_server
%production.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
%production.db.user=root
%production.db.pass=mypass
```

If there is anything that looks wrong in the verbose settings, this could be responsible for why your shortcut settings are not making sense.

If the configuration looks fine, I would check that your database is accessible.

For reference, here is the application.conf database options - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#dbconf

Comment: The settings are fine, so check...your db is accessible, the port is the standard port and that your user has access to the db...your db name or user are likely culprits

Comment: Finally, I made it to solve the problem. First, I created the database in mysql server manually, and I set the jpa.ddl to update, and it worked. Shouldn't the "create" option create the database if not presence? Any idea?